# Conda cloning environment - is the cloned environment synced with the "parent env"? how to cut off the sync?

Tags: conda

I used `conda create -n <new env> --clone <parent env>` to create a new env.  I found that if I modify things in the , the parent env is also modified so the two are synced.  Is this how it is supposed to be?  How to cut off this synchronization?

Comment: What exactly is meant by "*modify things*"? As in upgrading a version (`conda update pandas`)? Or like manually editing a .py file under the `site-packages`?

Comment: `--clone` does not exists for `install`. I get `conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --clone`. Is that the command that you used?

Comment: Hi,  sorry for the typo.  I meant it to be ''conda create -n < > --clone <parent env>''.

Comment: Instead of prose, try adding to the question body an example of how you "*modify things*" (e.g., `conda install -n newenv somepkg`) and the evidence for how you determine that this is also modifying the parent (e.g., checking `conda list`). Code (bash commands) are much more precise than prose, and those competent to help certainly will understand the code.

Comment: thanks for your help. See if the following is clearer.   1) `conda create -n <env2> --clone <env1>`  2) `conda activate <env2>` 3) conda install -c conda-forge <pkg>` 4) `pip install <pkg1>` 5) conda activate <env1>` 6) `conda list` & `pip list`  The observation is that `<pkg>` and `<pkg1>` installed in `<env2>` were also installed in `<env1>`.

Comment: Sorry to repeat, but please *edit* the question body with this new information. From the looks of it, seems like activation is not working correctly. I cannot replicate this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the `--copy` flag when using `conda create`. That will sever all the links back to the original environment and package cache.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  by "modify things" I meant that after I have a environment created by cloning from the other, the newly installed packages in the new cloned env were also installed in its "parent env".  All changes in one env are synced in the other.